# DJANGO and HTMX: Dependent dropdown is not populated, even though the values are valid in the console

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, htmx

**(If anyone reads this question again, i've improved the code and the text, and add various new screenshot, including two below all: now it is clearer and more understandable)**

I have three dropdowns and they are all dependent between them. The first and two dropdowns work fine, all ok, while the third dropdown doesn't work: it's empty with nothing inside.

The first dropdown menu, called `trip_selector`, correctly returns eg Spain, England, France. If I select Spain, then the second dropdown, called `trip`, is activated which correctly returns Madrid-Barcelona, Seville-Bilbao, etc. So, far so good, all ok, everything works fine.

**THE PROBLEM:** The problem is the **third dropdown** called `extract_single_city` in `views.py`, or in `extract_single_city.html`. In console i tried to print the items I would like to populate the dropdown (`print(x)`, `print(y)` and `print(options)`), and they print for example Madrid and Barcelona values correctly, but I can't populate them in the dropdown. I don't get any errors.
[image]

**WHAT I WANT:**

- I would like to make the second `trips` dropdown dependent on the third `extract_single_city`. As you can see I use HTMX. I wish that when I select in the second dropdown (called `trips`) for example Madrid-Barcelona then the third dropdown should be populated in `extract_single_city.html`with Madrid and Barcelona, one for each item:
  [image]
  So I would like to populate `extract_single_city.html` dropdown with `option` (i.e. `x` and `y`) of the function `def extract_single_city`. I would like to use split() and loop (for) for educational purposes
- For the sake of order and cleanliness, i would like to use all dropdowns in one file (`forms.html`). Currently in `forms.html` there is only first dropdown, then second and third dropdown are external html pages like `trips.html` and `extract_single_city.html`. So I would like to **delete** `trips.html` and `extract_single_city.html` and use all dropdowns in forms.html

**IMPORTANT NOTES (FOR INFORMATIONAL PURPOSES ONLY):**

I would use a `for` loop in the html page, and then in views.py I would use `split()` and `options = [x, y]`:

- I know I may not use the `loop` (`for`) in html page, but if possible: for educational purposes I would like to use the loop (for)
- I know I may not be using `split`, so write `options = [trip.city_departure, trip.city_destination]` directly, but let me explain: just for info, for example if in the third dropdown I select `Madrid-Barcelona`, I will need `x = Madrid, and y = Barcelona` to call it in future in web app code. So I thought about creating two separate variables like `x` and `y`, and use list like `options = [x, y]` to scroll in the dropdown. Either way, either I use one way or I use another way it doesn't matter, because this doesn't imply that the code of my question doesn't currently work

What am I doing wrong? Am I doing something wrong in `views.py`, something in the html page or something in `HTMX`?

**CODE:**

**extract_single_city.html**

```
<select name="extract_single_city" id="id_extract_single_city" style="width:200px;" 
        hx-get="{% url 'extract_single_city' %}" 
        hx-target="#id_extract_single_city" 
        hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator" 
        hx-trigger="change" 
        hx-swap="none">

    <option value="">Please select</option>

    {% for i in options %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    
</select>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Full_Record
import random
from django.db.models import F

def trip_selector(request):
    countries = Full_Record.objects.values(pk=F('country__id'), name=F('country__name')).distinct()
    trips = []
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'countries': countries, 'trips': trips})


def trips(request):
    if request.GET.get("country"):
        country = request.GET.get('country')
        trips = Full_Record.objects.filter(country=country)

    elif request.GET.get("trips"):
        selected_trip_id = int(request.GET.get('trips'))
        selected_trip = Full_Record.objects.get(id=selected_trip_id)
        request.session.update({"selected_trip_id": selected_trip_id})
        trips = Full_Record.objects.filter(country=selected_trip.country)

    return render(request, 'trips.html', {"trips": trips})
    
#THIRD DROPDOWN: ERROR???
def extract_single_city(request):
    if request.GET.get("trips"):
        trip = Full_Record.objects.get(id=request.session.get("selected_trip_id"))
        partita = f"{trip.city_departure}-{trip.city_destination}"

        x,y = trip.split('-')
        options = [x, y]

        context =  {"options": options}

        print("This is test of option", options) 
        print("This is test of single x", x) 
        print("This is test of single y", y) 

    return render(request, 'extract_single_city.html', context)
```

And more:

**forms.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}

<!-- First Combobox -->
<label for="id_country">Country</label>

<select name="country" id="id_country" 
        hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}" 
        hx-target="#id_trip" 
        hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator" 
        hx-trigger="change"
        hx-swap="outerHTML">

  <option value="">Please select</option>
  {% for country in countries %}
  <option value="{{ country.pk }}">{{ country.name }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

<!-- Second Combobox ??????? (non lo so)-->
<label for="id_trip">Trip</label>
{% include "trips.html" %}


<!-- Third Combobox -->
<label for="id_extract_single_city">Soggetto</label>
<select name="extract_single_city" id="id_extract_single_city" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>

{% endblock %}
```

**trips.html**

```
<!-- Second Combobox -->
<select name="trips" id="id_trip" style="width:200px;"  
        hx-get="{% url 'extract_single_city' %}?trip_id={{ trip.id }}" 
        hx-target="#id_extract_single_city" 
        hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator" 
        hx-trigger="change" 
        hx-swap="outerHTML">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    {% for trip in trips %}
        <option value="{{ trip.id }}">{{ trip.city_departure }}-{{ trip.city_destination }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.trip_selector, name="trip_selector"),
    #path('', views.trips, name='trips')
    path('trips', views.trips, name='trips'),
    path('result', views.result, name='result'),
    path('extract_single_city', views.extract_single_city, name='extract_single_city'),

]
```

## **UPDATE**

I insert the code of `models.py`, of `admin.py`, and two screenshots below of `admin panel`. Sorry if I didn't include this. I didn't think it was important

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey
from  django.contrib import admin

############ BASIC DATA ############

#Country
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


#City
class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

############ FULL RECORD ############

class Full_Record(models.Model):
   
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    city_departure = ChainedForeignKey(
        City,
        related_name='city_departure_name',
        chained_field="country",
        chained_model_field="country",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    
    city_destination = ChainedForeignKey(
        City,
        related_name='city_destination_name',
        chained_field="country",
        chained_model_field="country",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)


    def trip(self):
        return f"{self.city_departure}-{self.city_destination}"
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country.name
```

**NOTE:** As you can see, first i insert the **basic data** `Country` and `City`, then in `Full_Record` I insert the line creating the combinations of trips (for example Madrid-Barcelona) from two dropdowns. As you can see, I use the data from `Full_Record`, because I get the countries and trip combinations from here

[image]

[image]

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Country, City, Full_Record

class Prossima(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ['id', 'country', 'trip']
admin.site.register(Full_Record, Prossima)


admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(City)
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>University</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- HTMX -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.3/dist/htmx.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container mt-4">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <!-- evitare che le richieste hx-post incorrano in errori CSRF con le viste Django -->
    <script>
        document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) => {
            event.detail.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = '{{ csrf_token }}'; //insert csrf token when performing AJAX request
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you all!!!

Comment: @Tarquinius 
In my front-end i'm using HTMX instead of Javascript. The problem posed in the question is not this

Comment: @Tarquinius Yes, true, in fact i use HTMX for this reason. In my code, for example, the second dropdown modifies after selecting an item in the first dropdown

Comment: Ok, got it. I am wondering why combobox 2 works... Because trips.html also calls `{% url 'seleziona_soggetto' %}` same as seleziona_soggetto.html. So I would assume both of them to fail. Could you please add the actual displayed error? Maybe some output from console or smth?

Comment: @Tarquinius I've recently been using both Django and HTMX. Initially my project only had two dropdowns: sampled in form.html and trips in trips.html. These two dropdowns are dependent. As you can see in form.html, sampled dropdown has hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}". While trips.html had hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}. Everything works fine. So I thought that in the third select_subject dropdown, to make it dependent on trips, I should write hx-get="{% url ' trips' %}" (as is sampled for trips, where the first sampled dropdown has hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}"). Maybe I'm wrong. Have you ever used HTMX?

Comment: I have never used HTMX. That's why I am asking for the error. I want to know if the problem lays within the HTMX or within the django code. That's also the reason why I recommend to add the tag of your frontend to this question. Because then HTMX people would view this question.

Comment: @Tarquinius I don't know either if the error is in the Django code or the HTMX. Yes, I wanted to add the Htmx tag, but I didn't want to give up one of the Django tags. But now I add Htmx which is better. However, at first glance, does the code of the function def select_subject and the loop for in select_subject.html seem correct to you? (as a basic use of Django)

Comment: Yes, `seleziona_soggetto` looks correct in my eyes. Also: Does the output of the print statements work properly? This should tell if it is working or not.

Comment: @Tarquinius Yes, the print output works correctly. Are you referring to select_subject of the function or the html? So the problem can be reduced to HTMX only?

Comment: And the function `seleziona_soggetto` runs two times, right? One time for 2nd combobox and one time for 3rd combobox. Could you in that function change `options = [x, y]` to `options = ["hello", "world"]` and reaffirm that this option is displayed in trips.html and seleziona_soggetto.html?

Comment: @Tarquinius No, the select_subject function only runs once in general. Only once for the third dropdown.

I tried replacing options = ["hello", "world"], but the dropdown doesn't populate. This option should only appear in select_subject.html, because trips.html displays Madrid-Barcelona, etc.

Practically in the first dropdown I select for example Spain. In the second dropdown I select for example Madrid-Barcelona. So far everything is working fine. Then in the third dropdown I would like to display for example Madrid and Barcelona

Comment: I don't understand that. Because second combobox (trips.html) **and** third combobox (seleziona_soggetto.html) trigger `hx-get="{% url 'seleziona_soggetto' %}"`. I think it is a bit confusing, that your final page gets passed the context `trips` multiple times. Atm you don't really know if the trips really get served by the dedicated view-function, or if the context variable is still alive from a previous view-function.

Comment: @Tarquinius Until there were only the first two dropdowns, the first dropdown triggered hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}", while the second dropdown triggered hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}" . This is because they are dependent. In this way the two dropdowns work correctly. Also in another forum they recommended this to me....After that, I added the third dropdown (seleziona_soggetto.html), but I needed to make the second dropdown (trips.html) dependent on the third dropdown. So I changed hx-get of trips.html: from url 'trips' to url 'seleziona_soggetto'. Maybe I made a mistake

Comment: In `trips.html` you have an uneccesary `hx-swap="none"` so HTMX will not swap the third select.

Comment: @Dauros I tried to remove it, but the third dropdown doesn't work either

Comment: I don't know whether this can actually be done without rendering further templates. [This example](https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/) suggests that the display value and the actual `value` will match and I can't find a way to separate the two so that the next request gives proper IDs to search for in subsequent backend calls (i.e. a database ID and not just the display value)

Comment: @roganjosh  I read in the chat that you have never used Django and HTMX, but you use Flask. I need it in Django. Yes, it can be done in Htmx. If you can help me I will be happy, otherwise I thank you all the same for your kindness :)

Comment: @Horiatiki it wouldn't matter which backend I used because HTMX is the issue and it just needs routes to respond. I don't think what you want is possible based on the documented example I showed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have completelty redone my solution owing to your correction.

**models.py**
I have substituted `ChainedForeignKey` fields with Django's nativeForeignKey fields as I don't see a need for a library. Also because I have never used it.

I also set a `property` method `departure_destination` (which you named trip and implemented as a method).

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class FullRecord(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city_departure = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="city_departure")
    city_destination = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="city_destination")

    @property
    def departure_destination(self):
        return f"{self.city_departure}-{self.city_destination}"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country.name
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import FullRecord, Country


def trip_selector(request):
    if "Hx-Request" in request.headers:
        trips = FullRecord.objects.none()
        if request.headers["Hx-Trigger"] == "id_trip":
            country_id = request.GET.get("country")
            if country_id != "":
                trips = FullRecord.objects.filter(country_id=country_id)
            return render(request, "trips.html", {"trips": trips})
        elif request.headers["Hx-Trigger"] == "id_extract_single_city":
            selected_trip = request.GET.get("trips")
            extracted_cities = []
            if selected_trip != "":
                trip = FullRecord.objects.get(id=int(selected_trip))
                trip_with_combined_names = trip.departure_destination
                split_trip = trip_with_combined_names.split("-")
                extracted_cities = split_trip
            return render(request, "extract-single-city.html", {"options": extracted_cities})
    else:
        countries = Country.objects.all()
        return render(request, "form.html", {"countries": countries})
```

**urls.py**
from django.urls import path
from .views import trip_selector

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", trip_selector, name="trips")
]
```

**form.html**

You can style it your way but you can take a look at the changes I made.

```
{% block main-content %}
    <div class="flex justify-between px-10 gap-5 mt-5">
        <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
            <!-- First Combobox -->
            <label for="id_country">Country</label>

            <select name="country" id="id_country">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                {% for country in countries %}
                    <option value="{{ country.pk }}">{{ country.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
            <!-- Second Combobox ??????? (non lo so)-->
            <label for="id_trip">Trip</label>
            <select name="trips" id="id_trip"
                    hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}"
                    hx-include="[name=country]"
                    hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator"
                    hx-trigger="change from:#id_country">
            </select>
        </div>

        <!-- Third Combobox -->
        <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
            <label for="id_extract_single_city">Extract single city</label>
            <select name="extract_single_city" id="id_extract_single_city"
                    hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}"
                    hx-include="[name=trips]"
                    hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator"
                    hx-trigger="change from:#id_trip">

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock main-content %}
```

**trips.html**

```
<option value="">Please select</option>
{% for trip in trips %}
    <option value="{{ trip.id }}">{{ trip.city_departure }}-{{ trip.city_destination }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

**extract_single_city.html**

```
<option value="">Please select</option>
{% for i in options %}
    <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**

As per your wish to get rid of `trips.html` and `extract_single_city.html` and use only `form.html`, the following changes should have it work fine.

First, import `format_html` from `django.utils.html`. Because we will be creating string as HTML, that function will take care of the potential security vulnerabilities.

Next create the `<option>` markup as you would in the HTML template. Then with a `for` loop, you create your options.

See the updated code.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import FullRecord, Country

def trip_selector(request):
    if "Hx-Request" in request.headers:
        print(request.headers["Hx-Trigger"])
        if request.headers["Hx-Trigger"] == "id_trip":
            country_id = request.GET.get("country")
            trips = FullRecord.objects.none()
            trips_options = "<option value=''>Please select</option>"
            if country_id != "":
                trips = FullRecord.objects.filter(country_id=country_id)
                for option in trips:
                    new_option = f"<option value={option.id}>{option.departure_destination}</option>"
                    trips_options += new_option
            return HttpResponse(format_html(trips_options))

        elif request.headers["Hx-Trigger"] == "id_extract_single_city":
            selected_trip = request.GET.get("trips")
            extracted_cities = []
            extracted_options = "<option value="">Please select</option>"
            if selected_trip != "":
                trip = FullRecord.objects.get(id=int(selected_trip))
                trip_with_combined_names = trip.departure_destination
                split_trip = trip_with_combined_names.split("-")
                extracted_cities = split_trip
                for option in extracted_cities:
                    new_option = f"<option value={option}>{option}</option>"
                    extracted_options += new_option
            return HttpResponse(format_html(extracted_options))
    else:
        countries = Country.objects.all()
        return render(request, "form.html", {"countries": countries})
```

**NOTE**
You only need to change the views file only. You can now delete both `trips.html` and `extract_single_city.html`, leave everything else as it is.

Comment: PART 1. I am getting an error from your code. Couldn't test your code because i get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'travel' HOWEVER I fix my question.If you re-read the question again, I've replaced all the spanish to english words both in the question and inside the django and html code. ESPECIALLY at the bottom I added models.py, admin.py and two screenshots of the admin panel. There is something wrong with your models.py and it is different from mine. Also, I saw that you in BookTrip have created resorts, while I don't use it (continue in next comment).

Comment: PART 2. (continuation of previous comment above). I apologize if my question was initially unclear or detailed. I think I fixed it. Now that you've better understood my code (with all the words in English), and now that you've seen my models.py, can you review your solution and adapt it to what I asked? Thank you

Comment: FOR PASSING READERS: I haven't solved the problem yet. If any reader wants to help me, I'll be happy to read other answers as well. Thanks to Macpherson Chigwenembe and thanks to anyone else who will reply

Comment: PART 1. I am sorry I didn't explain that part. I was testing my solution in an existing project I'm working on, so I just made an app, named it 'travel'. Because I'm using a namespace in my main urls module, I had to refer to each named url by the name of app it belongs to. You can simply replace it with relevant url paths according to your setup.  I will take a look at your code, and see how to help further.

Comment: I didn't understand much (for translation reasons). I'm waiting for you to improve your solution, solving this problem and fixing the adaptation of your solution to my updated models.py. Unfortunately the bounty + 50 is running out, I hope you can make it in time. P.S: Please note that in my class of models i DON'T use your "Resort"

Comment: I have updated my solution, take a try.

Comment: PART 1. (continue in comment below). I tested your code, but there is a problem. In the Django Administrator everything is ok for inserting data into the database. The problem occurs when I select the second dropdown (Trip), because it is not populated and does not open. For example if I select Spain in the first dropdown, then the second dropdown is not activated (consequently not even the third one). Can you review your code please? Thank you

Comment: PART 2. In my initial question of the post (in IMPORTANT NOTES), however, I asked to remove trips.html and extract_single_city.html to use the 3 dropdowns all inside forms.html. You are still using trips.html and extract_single_city.html. Could you review your code to understand why the second dropdown doesn't fire, and then could you remove trips.html and extract_single_city.html and use all the code inside form.html? Is it NOT possible to use all the dropdowns inside form.html WITHOUT using the django forms approach? (continued below in part 3)

Comment: PART 3. (continuation of part 1 and 2). Summary to avoid confusion. The solution I would like, is to remove trips.html and extract_single_city.html and use all the dropdowns inside forms.html.

IF it's NOT possible (as asked in the main question), then I also accept the current solution you used. But if we use the current solution with external trips and extract_single_city, then I'd like to see a workaround with django forms as well (like you did initially when you gave me 2 solutions). P.S: Don't forget the problem that the second dropdown doesn't activate.Thank you

Comment: PART 4. (continuation of parts 1, 2, 3). Meanwhile, I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: PART 1. Can you check the server and see if HTMX is making the required requests when you select from the dropdowns? If no requests are being made, then it's probably that HTMX is not setup correctly in your project. If it's able to make the requests, you should note any errors it's displaying. I can then take it from there.

Comment: Implementing the same functionality without using Django forms or HTML partials is possible. You would just need to create the HTML in the view itself. Then return an HttpResponse. I will find time to give you an example. However, I don't find it clean because you're basically writing HTML at the backend. That's why I favour using forms instead.

Comment: how can i check if the server is making the requested requests when you select from the drop down menu? In my initial application design, requests were being made correctly (first and second dropdown)

Comment: Just look at the terminal you started the server from. Where you run the manage.py runserver command. When you select from the dropdown, check the terminal (the server) if it changes. I like to put my terminal and the browser window side by side.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you were referring to Chrome. In the terminal where I started the server nothing shows when I select and click a drop down menu. I used your code

Comment: Check your base.html. If nothing at all happens, then it is the problem with HTMX. See it it's added correctly. See if your form.html is extending from your base.html.

Comment: I had copied your form.html and replaced everything by also deleting {% extends 'base.html' %}. You are right, {% extends 'base.html' %} was missing. I have now added it, but when I start the project I get a blank all white screen and there is no dropdown. I don't understand what the problem is. I've updated my question and added the base.html which I use to show you. It worked fine before I applied your code.

Comment: Forget it. The problem was that you use "main-content" in block, while I used "content". Now I see the 3 dropdowns correctly and the second dropdown works. But the third dropdown doesn't work correctly good. For example, when from the second dropdown I select and click Madrid-Barcelona, then the third dropdown remains empty and is not activated

Comment: False alarm. The problem was your careless error :) In a line in views.py you had written extract-single-city.html and not extract_single_city. Now everything works correctly. The third dropdown also works correctly. You are great! :) But the problem remains that in the question I asked to delete extract_single_city.html and trip.html and to use all the dropdowns inside forms.html

Comment: All ok :), double check the previous comment. But the problem remains that in the question I asked to delete extract_single_city.html and trip.html and to use all the dropdowns inside forms.html

Comment: I'm glad that it's working fine now. I will update my answer the soonest. I will remember no Django forms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255166/discussion-between-mcpherson-and-horiatiki).